# How to set Dogecoin Wallet Encryption?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, dogecoin

Should I make a `Dogecoin` wallet addresses encryption?

If yes, what are the pros and cons and how it is made on linux - `Ubuntu 13.10`?

Comment: @GregHewgill I can see how this can help me to enable encryption in my situation?

Comment: Encryption of a Dogecoin wallet is pretty much the same as encryption of a Bitcoin wallet, so the answers to the linked question are applicable here. Whether or not you *should* encrypt your wallet, that's up to you.

Comment: @GregHewgill The `Dogcoin` wallet has  built-in encryption - since in a lot of tutorials it it shown. In github there is ticket about issues with this interface, which I can say is totally missing in Ubuntu 12.10 and wallet version 1.5.1